# getting error of illegal thread calling after migration from visual studio 2003 to visual studio 2005

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have converted my tool code from visual studio 2003 to visual studio 2005 and getting illegal cross threading exception at runtime while on another machine with the same configurations there is no error and the tool is working fine.

Can there be any specific reason to the happening?

Thanks

Comment: With 2003 to 2005 conversion came the .NET Framework 1.1 to 2.0 conversion. Cross thread calls have always been a problem in .NET, prior to 2.0 your application would just act strange sometimes, with 2.0 you get exceptions. Exceptions are helpful. Use them to improve your code.

Answer (score -1):

There is new property since VS 2005 `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` which is set to `true` in debugger mode by default. If you can live with unhandled cross thread calls, you can disable the check by setting:

```
Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
```

But it's always a better idea to handle exceptions instead of ignore them.

Comment: Yes i have already used Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls but i want to know why the same code is throwing exception on one machine while not on another since there is no change in configuration.

Comment: @vijaya this exception should be thrown in debugger only. How do you run the application on the different machine, directly or in VS debugger?

Comment: same visual studio 2005 is being used on both machines to run the code

Comment: @vijaya on both machines Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false and you still see illegal cross threading exception? This should be impossible. Maybe there is another exception?

Comment: i have resolved the exception using Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false already, the reason behind posting the question is i want to know why same code acted differently on two machine which have same configurations.

Comment: i got exception only on one machine(resolved using the control) while no exception on another.Need to know the reason only.

Comment: @vijaya well, maybe another machine has only one CPU core, or different OS or something else that prevented cross thread calls, but you didn't get the exception just by accident

Answer (score -1):

You can workaround the issue with typing the following command to your form's load function.

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
 }
```